touchmove event listener stops firing on mobile when updating a ref, works fine on desktop
I am working on a schedule component in React, the relevant code is available in this code sanbox.
And can be accessed here: https://6rcv9w.csb.app/
As the console logs show the touchmove event stops firing when dragging a time block up, curiously this only happens on mobile even though both desktop and mobile have the exact same logic. I tested it on a real device to discard the possibility that this is something to do with the developer tools.
I have narrowed it down to the event not firing if these two lines are present:
// This line causes the problem
delete timeBlocksRef.current[dayIndex]?.[hourIndex];

timeBlocksRef.current[dayIndex][startingHourStep] = value;

// And this one causes the problem as well
activeTimeBlockIdRef.current = `${dayIndex}-${startingHourStep}`;

If either of these lines is present then the listener stops triggering until the screen is touched again, the listener keeps triggering if both are commented out.
What is the cause for this behavior? As far as I can tell those two lines should not interfere with the event listeners and it the fact that it only happens when running on mobile makes it all the more puzzling. Are the changes to the ref somehow interfering with the listeners? The listeners are not removed nor added when the problem happens.

Maybe It's because of throttling, you can try wrapping the function

Tried addling throttling but the behavior is the same :(
